# How can I refactor converting this array into a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

Given this array (generated from a file)

```
["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"], 
["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"], 
["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]]
```

I convert it to a hash indexed by the second element (the sku) with the code below:

```
result = Hash.new([])
trans_data.each do |arr|
  result[arr[1]].empty? ? result[arr[1]] = [[arr[0], arr[2]]] : result[arr[1]] << [arr[0], arr[2]] 
end
result
```

This outputs the hash in the format I want it:

```
{"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ["Scranton", "68.76 USD"]], "DM1182"=>[["Yonkers", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "58.58 AUD"], ["Camden", "54.64 USD"]]}
```

I don't feel like my code is... clean. Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

EDIT: So far I was able to replace it with: `(result[arr[1]] ||= []) << [arr[0], arr[2]]`

With no default value for the hash

Comment: Is this an office reference? DM = Dunder Mifflin? :)

Comment: A perfect question, giving input and expected output and what you tried so far. Well done!

Comment: @ThomasKlemm Actually, the expression at the beginning is not a valid Ruby expression. And it is not explained what `trans_data` is. And I don't know what sku means.

Comment: @sawa That might be awkward for some people but certainly it wouldn't stop you from helping, guessing what he's looking for and pointing him in the right direction. I'm sure that you'll answer this question just as marvelously no matter what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like people need to learn about [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
ary = [
  ["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"],
  ["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"],
  ["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]
]
hash = ary.group_by{ |a| a.slice!(1) }
```

Which results in:

```
=> {"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ["Scranton", "68.76 USD"]], "DM1182"=>[["Yonkers", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "58.58 AUD"], ["Camden", "54.64 USD"]]}
```

---

It's possible to write this fairly succinctly without `slice!`, allowing `ary` to remain unchanged, and without the need to pull in any extra classes or modules:

```
irb(main):036:0> Hash[ary.group_by{ |a| a[1] }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.map{ |a,b,c| [a,c] } ] }]
=> {"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ["Scranton", "68.76 USD"]], "DM1182"=>[["Yonkers", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "58.58 AUD"], ["Camden", "54.64 USD"]]}
irb(main):037:0> ary
=> [["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"], ["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]]
```

---

Several other answers are using `each_with_object`, which removes the need to coerce the returned array to a hash using `Hash[...]`. Here's how I'd use `each_with_object` to avoid a bunch of line-noise inside the block as they try to initialize unknown keys:

```
ary.each_with_object(Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(a, b, c), h| 
  h[b] << [a, c] 
}
=> {"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ["Scranton", "68.76 USD"]], "DM1182"=>[["Yonkers", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "58.58 AUD"], ["Camden", "54.64 USD"]]}
```

This takes advantage of `Hash.new` taking an initialization block that gets called when a key hasn't been previously defined.

Comment: No, it's all Ruby; It's a great language.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this works?? I mean it looks like it sets the key as a[1] (which is cut with slice! and removes it from the array) and has the values set to whatever is left over. I looked at the documentation here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by But I still don't understand how it works

Comment: I will go with this answer. `+1` to you.

Comment: @Senjai, that's what Ruby is doing.

Comment: You have `ary = [a1, a2, a3]`, where `a1 = [1,2,3]`, so `a1[1] == a1.slice!(1) && a1 = [1,3]`

Comment: @Senjai `a.slice!(1)` removes the second element from each sub-array and returns it. `group_by` groups the (remaining) arrays by this key. You could also use `ary.group_by{|a| slice(1)}` (without `!`) if you don't want `ary` to be changed.

Comment: @Stefan, with `slice!` the result is not the same. Anyway, code that modifies the input is always dubious, I definitely would prefer to see a functional implementation. Unfortunately the Ruby core is missing some handy abstractions so it's more verbose.

Comment: @tokland you're right. It was "working" because I ran the `slice!` one before.

Comment: @Stefan: what happened to you is a good example of why destructive updates are bad, idempotence and referential transparency down the drain :-) I added a functional one for those interested.

Comment: "You could also use ary.group_by{|a| slice(1)} (without !) if you don't want ary to be changed." I'd normally write it without `!`, but, because the goal was to have the second element stripped, using `slice(1)!` became the logical choice as it killed two birds with one stone. I agree that it's better to write code that groups then modifies as two separate steps because it's more understandable/cleaner. However, when programming, verbose is sometimes good, sometimes bad. In this case the shorter code accomplished the required task directly. It'd have gotten ugly without `!`. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Functional approach using the abstraction [Enumerable#map_by](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/map_by.rb) from Facets:

```
require 'facets'
records.map_by { |name, key, price| [key, [name, price]] }
#=> {"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ... }
```

It's a pity that Ruby does not ship `map_by` within the core, it's a very useful (as it's unknown) variation of `Enumerable#group_by` (where you choose the grouping key **and** the value to accumulate).

Comment: I just checked `map_by`. I think it is tricky to use it, particularly when the second element of an array is falesy. For example, `[[:a, true], [:b, false]].map_by{|v1, v2| [v1, v2]}` gives `{
  :a => [true],
  :b => [[
    :b,
    false
  ]]
}`, which is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @sawa, you are right, but that's not a problem of the abstraction per se, it's a bug in the implementation: it should do a more thorough check of the returned value or drop the "act like group_by" 'feature' altogether (it makes no sense, if I want something to act like `group_by`... I use `group_by`). Of course it should return `{:a=>[true], :b=>[false]}`. I'll open a ticket.

Comment: Facets has some very usable code it in, similar to Rails. I'd like to see the core team do some cherry picking and pull in more of the utility methods from both. Active Support has some great tools I often pull in though I seldom work in Rails.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
result = trans_data.each_with_object({}) do |arr, hash|
  (hash[arr[1]] ||= []) << [arr[0], arr[2]]
end
```

Comment: I didn't even know each_with_object existed. so that passes in an empty hash every iteration? Or is it persistent.

Comment: Let's say it keeps track of the object's object_id you passed. So you don't need to *repass* the object each time like in `inject`.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Excellent. Thanks for teaching me something new and taking your time out to help others :)

Comment: Aha! I didn't know about each_with_object either. Updating!

Answer (score 2):

Note: Accepted answer is best answer, but I'm really happy with the weird awesomeness I use and how I explain it:

```
arr = [["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"], 
["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"], 
["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]]
 arr.each_with_object({}){|(a, b, c), hash| (hash[b] || hash[b]=[]).push [a,c]}
```

Props to Older God for each_with_object!

Explanation:
There are two wacky things going on here. The first, the `(a, b, c)` magic, I think it works like this:

```
( 

  #This bit:
  arr.collect{|(a,b,c)| "#{a}#{b}#{c}"}

) - (

  #Is equivalent to this bit:
  (0..arr.size).collect {|i|
    (a,b,c) = arr[i] #=> (a,b,c) = ["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"]
    "#{a}#{b}#{c}"
  }

  #as you can see, they generate identical arrays:
) == []
```

Note that you can treat the parens as implicit in certain circumstances: `arr.collect{|a, b, c| [a, b, c]} == arr`

The second wacky thing:

```
(hash[b] || hash[b]=[]).push(...)
```

Remember that everything in Ruby is both an expression and a reference.

```
[

 (hash[:a] || "foo") == (nil || "foo"),
 (hash[:b]=[]) == [],
 (hash[:b]=[]) === hash[:b],
 (hash[:b] || "foo") == ([] || "foo"),

] == [true, true, true, true]
```

`hash[b]`, when the key does not exist, evaluates to `nil` (which is falsey), so we evaluate and return the second half: `hash[b]=[]` which returns the value of the assignment, which is the array now referenced by `hash[b]`, so we can push on to it, and `hash[b]` will [still be a] reference the updated array.

:D

PS - This is, I think, the first Ruby question I've ever answered, and it's the first time I've ever even thought of, let alone be able to, turn the comments into code, and oh my do I like it. Thank you for the puzzle!

Comment: I love your use of short circuit eval here! Brilliant

Comment: What you are calling "wacky" aren't really wacky at all. They might have surprised you, but they're logical uses of the language. We used the `||` trick for assignment, or initialization then assignment, in Perl years ago. It's probably borrowed from shell scripting with a bit different syntax, or C.

Comment: It's totally inherited from Perl (I did Perl before I did Ruby), and it's one of the things that I love about ruby is that is has fewer "things" and those things are more similar: everything is an expression, everything is a reference. These kind of tricks are less readable when you first start programming, but as you start gaining the concepts, they're /absolutely/ natural.

Comment: (Well, and I think Perl probably got it from Lisp, which got it from... and gave it to...)

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
arr = [["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"], ["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]] 

hash = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}

 arr.each{|a| hash[a[1]].push([a[0],a[2]])}


   hash => {"DM1210"=>[["Yonkers", "70.00 USD"], ["Scranton", "68.76 USD"]], "DM1182"=>[["Yonkers", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "58.58 AUD"], ["Camden", "54.64 USD"]]}
```

Comment: Ahh, so that's the right way to set the default value. Previously my hash would be empty unless I indexed it.

Answer (score 0):

More or less extracted from the [facets library](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/master/lib/core/facets/enumerable/map_by.rb) tokland suggests:

```
ary = [["Yonkers", "DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["Yonkers", "DM1182", "19.68 AUD"], ["Nashua", "DM1182", "58.58 AUD"], ["Scranton", "DM1210", "68.76 USD"], ["Camden", "DM1182", "54.64 USD"]]

hash = {}
ary.each{ |a,b,c| (hash[b] ||= []) << [a,c] }

hash
# => {"Camden"=>[["DM1182", "54.64 USD"]], "Nashua"=>[["DM1182", "58.58 AUD"]], "Scranton"=>[["DM1210", "68.76 USD"]], "Yonkers"=>[["DM1210", "70.00 USD"], ["DM1182", "19.68 AUD"]]}
```